# understanding recursion in a function which uses generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, generator

Here is a function

```
def flatten(nested):
   try:
        for sublist in nested:
            for element in flatten(sublist):
                yield element
   except TypeError:
       yield nested
```

and `nested=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]`

what I am trying to understand is when the function flatten is called for the first time
entire sequence `([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]])` is passed to it ,following is the sequence of execution I understood

```
 flatten([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]):
   try:
        for sublist in ([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]):
            for element in flatten(sublist):
```

here a call to flatten is made and it starts over the list element [1,2] which is nested[0]

now in this recursive call to flatten it goes the following way

```
 flatten([1, 2]):
   try:
        for sublist in ([1, 2]):
            for element in flatten(sublist):
```

but in last case [5]
what goes is

```
  for sublist in ([5]):
                for element in flatten(sublist):
```

Now here in the recursive call how does flatten work? that I am not clear also if ,
the input is not a well defined list the input is following list`[[[1],2],3,4,[5,[6,7]],8]`

then how do recursive calls take place, I am not clear with this thing.

Comment: you can see the try...except block as if(type(nested) == list ) ...else #type(nested) == integer

Answer (score 1):

```
def flatten(nested, depth=0):
    print "-> %d : %s" % (depth, nested)
    try:
        for sublist in nested:
            print " s %d : %s" % (depth, sublist)
            for element in flatten(sublist, depth+1):
                print " e %d : %s" % (depth, element)
                yield element
    except TypeError:
        print " y %d : %s" % (depth, nested)
        yield nested
```

You can trace through exactly how it's working with the above...

Answer (score 1):

In line number 4, flatten is called again.
When an element is reached, Type error is triggered, and it is yielded.

Otherwise flatten is called again.

Comment: yes because "for sublist in (5):" throws error, 5 is avalue not a iterable list (example)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python guy, but it seems to me that this faltten works like this:

1. It will recursively try to call itself for each element, until TypeError occurs
2. When TypeError occurs that means that this element is not a collection and could not be flatten further so it will yield this element.

Example: `flatten [[[1],2],3,4,[5,[6,7]],8]`:

```
1st call 1st step: sublist = [[1],2]
2nd call 1st step: sublist = [1]
3nd call 1st step: type error | yield : [1]
2nd call 2nd step: type error | yield : [1,2]
1st call 2nd step: type error | yield : [1,2,3]
```

....
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add logging to understand when certain method is executed and with which arguments:

```
def flatten(nested):
    print(nested)
    try:
        for sublist in nested:
            for element in flatten(sublist):
                yield element
    except TypeError:
        yield nested
```

And the call order will be like this:

```
[[[1], 2], 3, 4, [5, [6, 7]], 8]
[[1], 2]
[1]
1
2
3
4
[5, [6, 7]]
5
[6, 7]
6
7
8
```